# using jQuery in Ruby input fields, utilising .prop() method to add disbaled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add and remove disabled attributes to input fields but am having no luck with .prop() method.

here is the html/ruby on rails

`

```
<div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <input  id="scheduled-checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
          <!-- checked="<%= !f.object.published_on.nil? %>" disabled="<%= f.object.published? %>" -->
      </span>
      <input disabled="" id="scheduled-date" class="form-control"  type="date" value="<%= f.object.published_on %>"></input>
    <%= f.input :published_on, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: f.object.published_on } %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <% if f.object.persisted? %>
    <%= f.submit I18n.t("rag.update"), name: :submit, value: :update,  class: "btn_default_1 add_margin_top form-control" %>
    <%= f.submit I18n.t("rag.publish_now"), name: :submit, value: :publish, class: "btn_default_1 add_margin_top form-control" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.submit I18n.t("rag.draft"), name: :submit, value: :draft,  class: "btn_default_1 add_margin_top form-control submit", id: :draft %>
    <%= f.submit I18n.t("rag.publish"), name: :submit, value: :publish, class: "btn_default_1 add_margin_top form-control submit", id: :publish %>
    <%= f.submit I18n.t("rag.schedule"), name: :submit, value: :schedule, class: "btn_default_1 add_margin_top form-control submit", id: :schedule  %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

here is the JS

```
`$("#scheduled-checkbox").change(function() {

    if ($("#scheduled-checkbox").is(':checked')) {
      console.log('box is checked'); //checked means PUBLISH submit button is disabled
      $("#scheduled-date").prop("disbaled:", true);
      $("#schedule").prop("disbaled:", false);
      $("#publish").prop("disbaled:", true);

    } else {
      console.log('box is unchecked');   //unchecked means SCHEDULE submit button is disbaled
      $("#scheduled-date").removeAttr('disabled', false);
      $("#schedule").removeAttr("disbaled:");
      $("#publish").removeAttr("disbaled:");

      console.log($("#scheduled-date").removeAttr('disabled'));
    }`
```

Comment: try `attr` instead of  `prop` with `attr("disabled","disabled")` when you want to add `disabled`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be

```
$("#scheduled-date").prop("disabled", true);
```

Instead of

```
$("#scheduled-date").prop("disbaled:", true);
```

And similarly for the next two lines

Answer (score 0):

look at your code. you  have set 'disbaled' instead of 'disabled'. so you can use .attr() method to define an attribute with jquery, like:

`$("#publish").attr("disabled", "disabled"); or $("#publish").attr("disabled", false);`.

Disabled attr doesn't permits take the input value to send in POST method, so you have to set the 'readonly' attribute, like this:

`$("#publish").attr("readonly", "readonly");` or `$("#publish").attr("readonly", false);`

or use .removeAttr() to remove attributes